# Cron not executing PHP script

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

Cron is running but for some reason it's not executing the script. I have checked to see if the script works and it does. I am trying to make the PHP script execute every minute.

```
* * * * * /etc/php5 /var/www/cron/automatedScript.php
```

The server is Linux, Ubuntu distro.

Comment: what happens if you run this from your terminal `/etc/php5 /var/www/cron/automatedScript.php`

Comment: Is `/etc/php5` the path of `php`? Sound strange, as it is normally in `/usr/bin`. Check it with `which php`. Also, does the file have executing permissions?

Comment: @duellsy "/etc/php5: Is a directory"

Comment: @fedorqui I thought it was but I must be wrong. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Ubuntu, I've pointed it to /usr/bin/php5, will see if it works now.

Comment: Just check it with `which php`. Then with the path you are given, try and do `.../path/php /var/www/cron/automatedScript.php` as @duellsy suggested.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, should I use /usr/bin/php5 if I'm using a PHP version above or equal to 5?

Comment: I guess, so. Just give a try to the command and see if it works. My feeling is that yes, you should use that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely giving it the wrong php executable path :)

On *MY* system it would be:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/cron/automatedScript.php
```

To confirm the correct path to use execute:

```
nm@vp:~$ which php
```

And this will return you the path similar to:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: If the PHP version is >= 5 should I use /usr/bin/php5?

Comment: Note that `/usr/bin/php` is one of the possible paths, it can be any other. See what we are talking in the comments of the question.

Comment: @fedorqui Its highly unlikely that he is going to have an exotic setup given that he is asking the question, but to appease the SO way - jskidd3 Run the command 'which php' and this will tell you.

Comment: @jskidd3 If my solution has resolved your question could you mark it as answered - this will assist others greatly in future looking for resolution. If my answer did not resolve it, let us know and we can give more help.

Comment: @NeilMasters It wasn't the solution to my problem. I eventually found out there was a problem in the PHP file itself, but I shall select it as best anyway as it may help someone else. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your problem

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/cron/automatedScript.php
```

Info : PHP path may be vary in different os. So you have to know right installtion path of PHP.